# If Mongo $lookup is a left outer join, then how come it excludes non-matching documents?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

The title says it all. How come if a document does not result in any matching outer document according to its matching field, then how come it's not included in the pipeline's result set?

I'm testing out the new aggregators in Mongo 3.2 and I've gone so far as to perform a nested array lookup by first unwinding, and then grouping the documents back up. All I have left is to have the results include all local documents that didn't meet the `$lookup` criteria, which is what I thought was the standard definition of "left outer join".

Here's the query:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$profile",
        $unwind: "$profile.universities"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "universities",
            localField: "profile.universities._id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "profile.universities"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            universities: {
                $addToSet: "$profile.universities"
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

So if I have a `user` that has an empty `profile.universities` array, then I need it to be included in the result set regardless of the `$lookup` returning any matches, but it does not. How can I do this, and any reason why Mongo constructed `$lookup` to operate this way?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This behavior isn't related to `$lookup`, it's because the default behavior for [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) is to omit documents where the referenced field is missing or an empty array.

To preserve the unwound documents even when `profile.universities` is an empty array, you can set its `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` option to `true`:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$profile",
        $unwind: {
            path: "$profile.universities",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "universities",
            localField: "profile.universities._id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "profile.universities"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            universities: {
                $addToSet: "$profile.universities"
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is the weirdest behavior I have ever seen, fought this bug for like a week, if it wasn't for your answer I would never try to see in that direction

Comment: How to write the above in c# ?