# How to use findOne and aggregate at the same time in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Say I have a list of users. A user has

```
username,
email,
password,
sketches
```

`sketches` is another collection, and a `sketch` has

```
title
author
```

If I want to fetch a user with his/her sketches, I have to use `aggregate` to find all `sketches` that have `author` as his/her `username`.

This is working great:

```js
const data = await userModel
  .aggregate([
    { $match: { username } },
    { $lookup: { from: 'sketches', localField: 'username', foreignField: 'author', as: 'sketches' } },
    { $limit: 1 }
   ]).toArray()
```

The issue is that some users don't have sketches; when a user has no sketches, the `aggregate` does not return anything else about the user, so `username`, `email`, and `password` becomes undefined.

Is there any way I can make `aggregate` sort of optional? Like find the user and *then* try to see if they have any sketches.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$lookup performs an outer join, it does not drop fields of the base document when there are no documents to join.

```
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.foo.insert({a:1})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.foo.aggregate([{$lookup:{from:'bogus',localField:'x',foreignField:'y',as:'z'}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f2c5fbd0b0bc72d0ed504d3"), "a" : 1, "z" : [ ] }
```

See also [If Mongo $lookup is a left outer join, then how come it excludes non-matching documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479875/if-mongo-lookup-is-a-left-outer-join-then-how-come-it-excludes-non-matching-do)